# Remove wildcard string from list

Tags: python

I have a list which is a large recurring dataset with headers of the form:

```
array = ['header = 1','0','1','2',...,'header = 1','1','2','3',...,'header = 2','1','2','3']
```

The header string *can* vary between each individual dataset, but the size of the individual datasets do not.

I would like to remove all of the headers so that I am left with:

```
array = ['0','1','2',...,'1','2','3',...,'1','2','3']
```

If the header string does not vary, then I can remove them with:

```
lookup = array[0]
while True:
    try:
       array.remove(lookup)
    except ValueError:
       break
```

However, if the header strings do change, then they are not caught, and I am left with:

```
array = ['0','1','2',...,'1','2','3',...,'header = 2','1','2','3']
```

Is there a way in which the sub-string "header" can be removed, regardless of what else is in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best use a list comprehension with a condition instead of repeatedly removing elements. Also, use `startswith` instead of using a fixed `lookup` to compare to.

```
>>> array = ['header = 1','0','1','2','header = 1','1','2','3','header = 2','1','2','3']
>>> [x for x in array if not x.startswith("header")]
['0', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

Note that this does not modify the existing list but create a new one, but it should be considerably faster as each single `remove` has O(n) complexity.

If you do not know what the header string is, you can still determine it from the first element:

```
>>> lookup = array[0].split()[0] # use first part before space
>>> [x for x in array if not x.startswith(lookup)]
['0', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and did seem to process quite quickly.  Thank you!

Comment: @DConstable In this case, please consider _accepting_ the answer to mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Using the find() method you can determine whether or not the word "header" is contained in the first list item and use that to determine whether or not to remove the first item.